# Git pull fails when I have a separate working dir

Tags: git

I have a repository that has a separate worktree. When I attempt to `git pull` it fails with a triple
`fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var/www)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).`

I'm launching this command from the git folder and not from the worktree.

Comment: When you say worktree, is this a linked worktree, generated with `git worktree add`?

Comment: @ffledgling I did `git --git-dir=. --work-tree=../workdir/ init`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your worktree add a file `.git` containing:

`gitdir: /path/to/your/repo/dir`

Otherwise, when you init the repo remember to use `--separate-git-dir`:

`git init --separate-git-dir <git dir>`